# Can normal reaction result from a pull?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I have understood the direction of normal reaction , but I'm confused whether it may result from a pull also or it results only from a push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Does pulling cause a normal reaction?

No, the normal reaction is only for pushing. If you meant 'pulling' as in how you open a door by pulling on its handle, that is also pushing. Even though we call it pulling, the inside of your hands is actually pushing on the door handle from the other side. Similarly, 'pulling' any object (rope, rod, another human, etc) with your hands is also pushing in disguise. Now if you are talking about pulling as in the sense of earth pulling a nearby asteroid towards itself, there is no normal reaction involved here. The normal reaction only appears for contact forces, and gravity is a non-contact force.

#### What is normal reaction?

When you try to run into a wall like in Harry Potter, do you actually go through it? No, you bang on the wall and come to rest. According to Newton's first law, if there was no external force acting on you, you should have kept on going. So there must be an external force from the wall that has caused this deceleration. And this force is what we call the normal reaction of the wall. At the molecular level, the electrostatic repulsion between the positively charged nuclei of the wall matrix and your body matrix is what causes this normal reaction.

So normal reaction is, by definition, only for cases that involve contact between two bodies that would otherwise go through each other. And you can call this 'pushing' if you want.

Answer (score 2):

What we usually call the normal reaction (or, sometimes, the "contact force") is a result of Newton's third law - if $A$ pushes $B$ with a force $F$ then $B$ pushes $A$ with an equal and opposite force. The same thing happens if $A$ pulls $B$ - then $B$ will pull $A$ with an equal and opposite force. The only difference is in the terminology - in the case that $A$ pulls $B$, we usually call the force between them "tension" or "friction" rather than a normal reaction.

Answer (score 2):

A normal reaction is whatever is needed to enforce some motion constraint. It exists in a perpendicular fashion to any allowed motion because normal reactions are not allowed to do any work, and force times a parallel displacement is the definition of work.

The nature of any applied forces on a system is not important here. Just that in the absence of the normal force the system would move in a way inconsistent with the constraints.

The normal force of a book on a table is such as to prevent the book from going through the table. The same for a block on a ramp. The block cannot be allowed to go into the ramp, but *is* allowed to slide along the ramp.

The forces applied to the block may be due to gravity, ropes, a person pushing or pulling, springs, magnets, aerodynamic forces, etc etc etc. The nature of the forces does not matter.

Comment: I disagree with much of the first paragraph. The normal force is a real contact force, not a fictitious bookkeeping force like centrifugal force, which can take whatever numerical value is required to explain what you observe. Normal forces can do work, and don't need to be perpendicular to motion. A person going up in an elevator experiences a normal force from the floor greater than their weight, causing them to accelerate upwards.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - where did I say it was fictitious? It is a real force needed for systems to obey constraints. In the case of the person-elevator system, it is not the normal force that does the work, but the cable force lifting the elevator. Normal forces can transfer energy from one part of the system, but they do not _generate_ work like other forces do. The normal force cannot make the person jump up. There is no _relative_ motion here and thus the work done is zero (due to Newton's 3rd law).

Comment: Not directly, but that's where my mind goes when a force is described as "whatever is needed to enforce some motion constraint". Fictitious forces take whatever magnitude is required to make the force diagram work out. The normal force is determined by physical interaction, not by constraints of the frame of reference. In the frame of the upward-accelerating elevator, there is no net force on the person, but the normal force is unchanged.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - I feel we have different terminology for the same things. My background is in robotics and kinematics and normal force(s) are just a sub-category of the more general term "constraint forces".

Answer (score 1):

This is really a semantics question.  There is no one answer, just as there is no one definition for an English word.  That being said, we can make some headway.

A phrase phrase "normal force," or "normal reaction," does not describe one force, but rather a class of them.  "Normal" in this case means perpendicular.  Any force/reaction that is perpendicular to a surface could be called a normal force.

What is typically special about the normal force is that those words are typically used to describe not just a perpendicular force, but a perpendicular force that varies in magnitude to achieve some constraint.  In the typical scenario, with a block on a table, the normal force is whatever force is needed to ensure the obvious constraint that the block cannot sink through the table.

It is unusual to see it used in terms of pulling, but that's more a nature of how we construct things.  Its difficult to construct a situation where you have a "normal force" going into the surface (rather than out of it) that is both always perpendicular *and* varies to achieve some constraint.  It happens often in pushing situations because two objects can slide across one another, but if you attempt to construct a similar situation with pulling, you find the objects simply move apart.  As AlphaLife points out in their answer, if you construct a situation where two objects can slide while being pulled apart, one typically finds that one object wrapped around another and instead was pushing on the far side.  Or, if you fuse the objects together completely, the result is typically treated as a single body, and we don't think of the pulling force at all (until one gets into discussing internal tension).